# How to control Next Track Item on MPMusicPlayer

Tags: iphone

In MPMusicPlayer i want to display MPMediaPickerView if the Next Track item are finished....
How this is possible on phone....Please help me....

Answer (score 0):

Watch for `MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification`, and in your `selector` method, check the `playbackState` for `MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped`, do other checking (maybe `nowPlayingItem`?), and present your view.

```
NSNotificationCenter * notifications = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [notifications addObserver:self selector:@selector (trackDidChangeWithNotification:)
                          name:MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification
                        object:self.iPodController];
```

.....

```
-(void)handleNextTrackNotification {
    if ([self.iPodController playbackState] == MPMusicPlaybackStateStopped) {
        // do whatever logic checks
        // present view
    }
}
```